# SSO Winforms(.Net) and SPA Application (Angular)?

Tags: angular, winforms, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, identityserver3

I want to be able to implement single sign on(SSO) between a winforms application and SPA app. The winforms application is using hybrid flow, I want to open the SPA application from winforms application with the same credentials that the user is logged in without having to prompt for credentials again.

I have implicit flow on the SPA application. Both these applications work fine with auth; as separate clients to the Identity server.

Answer (score 0):

The winforms app should use the system browser for logins and you will then achieve SSO between the two, since they will share a session cookie from the identity provider. You can't get App A to control App B's login behaviour though (without hacks). Desktop logins are tricky and some posts of mine may help you to understand usability + security trade offs: https://authguidance.com/2018/01/26/final-desktop-sample-overview/

Comment: Thank you very much! That makes sense. Thanks for pointing me to your posts. This gives us a good start.